# Getting an error while using Microsoft.AppCenter with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Microsoft.AppCenter nuget to a Xamarin app. Xamarin.Android is building fine. But I am getting an error while trying to build the Xamarin.iOS app.

> MTOUCH: Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kMSLongTypedPropertyType. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

I have tried the solution mentioned in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#MT5210

But I am still getting the error while I am trying to build Xamarin.iOS app. I am using the below configurations:

- Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
- Version 8.4.4 (build 91)
- Xamarin.iOS
- Version: 13.10.0.17 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: Hi , you can first update the version of VS to the latest version to have a try again .

Comment: I have the same issue. Are you using Firebase packages by any chance?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT : Thanks for the response. I was able to fix this issue by installing  `Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics` and  `Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes` nugets. Does it mandatory to install these two nugets if we need to use Microsoft.AppCenter ? Could you please confirm?

Comment: @Woj : I am not using Firebase Packages. May be you could try installing the nugets which I had mentioned in my above comment.

Comment: I have both of them. In my project for some reason, Firebase Packages and AppCenter packages dont like each other on iOS project.

Comment: @Ane Glad you find the solution . If your code related to `Analytics` or `Crashes` , you need to install them . By the way , you can share the solution in answer when you have time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got fixed after installing `Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics` and `Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes`. As @Junior Jiang - MSFT mentioned, if code uses microsoft app center to get the analytics and crashes, we need to install these two nugets along with `Microsoft.AppCenter`. Thanks.